# Does Heroku support Play 2.1?

Tags: heroku, playframework, playframework-2.1

Their Play page was updated on August 2012, and only mentions Play 2.0.

Do they support Play 2.1? I did find a few questions here about deployment of Play 2.1 apps to Heroku, so I assume it is working and the documentation was just never updated. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this our, we've updated our docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play-support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Play2.1 works fine on Heroku. Just try :)

Comment: Just deployed ... compilation took a long time, but it seems to be working!

Answer (score 1):

Works fine but it's good to know that they don't support websockets (yet) in case your app uses it. I think the only one that supports it is AWS.